# How to speed up these graphics functions?

Tags: c#, winforms, drawing

Here are a couple of methods I'm using in my application

This 'highlights' an area selected (called on a MouseMove event, so it's used very often to give a live view of what you've selected).

Ignore the scaling variable, this is so that if the image has been resized to fit the control the selected area is reflected properly

```
private Bitmap DrawCropArea(Bitmap bm, Rectangle area)
{
    int x = (int)Math.Round(area.X / scaling);
    int y = (int)Math.Round(area.Y / scaling);
    int cropWidth = (int)Math.Round(area.Width / scaling);
    int cropHeight = (int)Math.Round(area.Height / scaling);

    using (Graphics gr = Graphics.FromImage(bm))
    {
        Brush brush = new Pen(Color.FromArgb(200, Color.DarkGray)).Brush;

        Rectangle rect1 = new Rectangle(0, 0, bm.Width, y);
        Rectangle rect2 = new Rectangle(0, y, x, cropHeight);
        Rectangle rect3 = new Rectangle(0, (y + cropHeight), bm.Width, bm.Height);
        Rectangle rect4 = new Rectangle((x + cropWidth), y, (bm.Width - x - cropWidth), cropHeight);

        gr.FillRectangle(brush, rect1);
        gr.FillRectangle(brush, rect2);
        gr.FillRectangle(brush, rect3);
        gr.FillRectangle(brush, rect4);
    }

    return bm;
}
```

And this sets the brightness and contrast, and like the previous method it's called very often as it's on 2 trackbar EditValueChanging events

```
private Bitmap ChangeBrightnessContrast(Bitmap bm, float cont, int bright)
{
    float[][] arr =
    {
        new float[] { 1, 0, 0, 0, 0 },
        new float[] { 0, 1, 0, 0, 0 },
        new float[] { 0, 0, 1, 0, 0 },
        new float[] { 0, 0, 0, 1, 0 },
        new float[] { 0, 0, 0, 0, 1 },
    };

    ColorMatrix cMatrix = new ColorMatrix(arr);
    cMatrix.Matrix00 = cMatrix.Matrix11 = cMatrix.Matrix22 = cont;
    cMatrix.Matrix40 = cMatrix.Matrix41 = cMatrix.Matrix42 = bright / 255.0F;

    ImageAttributes imgAttributes = new ImageAttributes();
    imgAttributes.ClearColorMatrix();
    imgAttributes.SetColorMatrix(cMatrix, ColorMatrixFlag.Default, ColorAdjustType.Bitmap);
    //imgAttributes.SetGamma(1.0F, ColorAdjustType.Bitmap);

    using (Graphics gr = Graphics.FromImage(bm))
    {
        gr.InterpolationMode = System.Drawing.Drawing2D.InterpolationMode.NearestNeighbor;
        gr.DrawImage(bm, new Rectangle(0, 0, bm.Width, bm.Height), 0, 0, bm.Width, bm.Height, GraphicsUnit.Pixel, imgAttributes);
    }

    return bm;
}
```

It's fine until I am using these on some larger images, where it starts to really lag.

I've been reading a lot of mixed information; GDI+ does support hardware acceleration, no it doesn't you should use Direct2D etc.. So I'm not sure if there's something I can change with the current Drawing libraries I'm using, if I should switch to something else, or if I should do a lot of legwork and turn the image been worked on into a lower resolution thumbnail, then re-apply all the adjustments to the fullsize image after the user is happy?

Comment: I'd avoid `FromImage`, it's a bit like `CreateGraphics`.  Don't you have `Paint` events available to you?  Always best to use that whenever possible.

Comment: I'm not too familiar with the Paint even, you mean that one that is on the picturebox control?

Comment: This not nec essarily good advice. It really depends on the use case. Does the graphics build up to a persistent result or is it only transient?

Comment: You don't tell us what 'really large' is but The latter idea of working on a thumbnail for the live-preview is certainly the safe way to good performance. There you can even use a separate thread to calculate the large image..

Comment: See [ControlPaint.DrawReversibleFrame Method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.controlpaint.drawreversibleframe(v=vs.110).aspx#Examples) for your selection rectangle.

Comment: @TaW it starts to get noticeably bad with images around 1920x1080 (or some similar overall pixel count) and above, though there's still a slight noticeable difference between a 720p and 408p image. I guess I will go with the thumbnail idea